# Как привести время сервера к времени, соответствующему часовому поясу пользователся?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

Здравствуйте.
В проекте на asp.net mvc 4 в базе данных создается запись с полем createdDateTime - дата и время создания: `record.createdDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;`
Сервер стоит где-то за бугром и в базу попадает "серверное" время создания. Соответственно пользователи, заходя из России (с разных часовых поясов), видят неверную дату создания записи.
Вопрос: как привести выводимую дату и время к часовому поясу пользователя?
Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Клиентское время в HTTP запросе не передаётся. Нужно выполнить на клиенте JS, который сообщит серверу часовой пояс клиента, чтобы в дальнейшем сервер мог форматировать даты под клиента.

Либо все даты должны на клиенте приводиться в свой часовой пояс, опять же, JavaScript'ом.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно задать время для сайта:

```
    namespaceUralTime 
{
    using System;

    public class dtUralTime
    {
        public static string UralTime()
        {
            //зимой
            string UralTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Ekaterinburg Standard Time")).ToString();
            return UralTime;
            //летом
            //string UralTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Bangladesh Standard Time")).ToString();
            //return UralTime;
        }

    }
}
```

Использование в коде страниц сайта:

```
txtDateTime.Text = dtUralTime.UralTime();
```

Может, это натолкнет в сторону поиска.